# Implementing LruCache for caching bitmap images

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, android-lru-cache

In my application I am fetching a feed from Internet. feed contains some text information and image. I have to store images in **LruCache**, for that I have referred [Google developer](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) website and implemented as shown in there. this implementation works fine. but since my application supports from api level 10, it show some error allocation cache size, I cant declare the size for cache sine I am using bitmap.getByteCount() it shows add `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)` notation,
and when I open the application in android 2.3 application stops responding

**Code**

```
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

    private LruCache<String,Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       manageCache();
    }

    private void manageCache() {
            mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(mCacheSize) {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
                @Override
                protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
                }
            };
        }
```

how can I support for api level 10 also, is there any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the in-memory size of the bitmap prior to API level 12 you may use this code:

```
int bitmapSize = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
```

So the method `sizeOf` will look like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
        return bitmap.getByteCount();
    } else {
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

*P.S. you have to return a size of a bitmap in bytes, so you must not divide bitmap.getByteCount() by 1024.*

Comment: Why adding target api version if you are comparing in inside function

Comment: To prevent IDE from showing a warning in the line ``bitmap.getByteCount()``